# Flutter Android Alarm Manager not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I have installed the [Android Alarm Manager](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager) plugin in my Flutter v1.0.0 app by following the instructions at the link. But when I try to use `AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(...)` nothing happens. There's not even an error in the console.

I am using a `FutureBuilder` widget to wait on the `AndroidAlarmManager.initialize()` future and one other future before my app begins rendering:

```
final combinedFutures = Future.wait<void>([
  gameService.asyncLoad(),
  AndroidAlarmManager.initialize(),
]);

FutureBuilder<void>(
  future: combinedFutures,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    ...
  }
)
```

The `FutureBuilder` does end up rendering what it should so I know that the `AndroidAlarmManager.initialize()` future returns correctly.

Then in a button's `onPressed` function I do this:

```
AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
  Duration(seconds: 5),
  0,
  () {
    print("test");
  },
  wakeup: true,
);
```

The above should be calling `print(test)` after 5 seconds and waking up my phone but nothing is printed to the console and nothing happens on my phone. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

After debugging the library code I found that the `AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot` function calls the method `PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callback)` where `callback` is the function passed in. In my case the `callback` function was:

```
() {
  print("test");
}
```

For some reason `PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle` was returning `null` when it should be returning a value of type `CallbackHandle`.

Looking at the `PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle` [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/PluginUtilities/getCallbackHandle.html) it says:

> Get a handle to a **named top-level or static callback function** which can be easily passed between isolates.

The function I was passing is not top-level, static, or named. So I did the following inside my class and everything works fine now:

```
static void alarmTest() {
  print("test");
}

void runAlarm() {
  AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
    Duration(seconds: 10),
    0,
    alarmTest,
    wakeup: true,
  ).then((val) => print(val));
}
```